# DatePickerDialog change the dialog size

Tags: java, android, layout, datepickerdialog

I need to show the DatePickerDialog in my apps. I would like to change the dialog size to bigger. 
I tried below code.

```
 WindowManager.LayoutParams params = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
 params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
 params.width = 1000; // dialogWidth;
 params.height = 1000; // dialogHeight;
 dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

But this is not work. So anybody know how can change the dialog size.
Thanks a lots.

Comment: Are you setting the attributes before or after you show the dialog?

Comment: do you mean the style?

Comment: I mean the code sample you provided? Especially `dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(params);`.